# Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apps')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

this is my firebase sdk version

```
firebase@9.0.2
```

this is init code of firebase  i cant solve this please help me for this error

```
export default function  initFirebase() {
    if(!firebase.apps.length){
        firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials)

        if(typeof window !=='undefined'){
            if('measurementId' in clientCredentials){
                firebase.analytics()
                firebase.performance()
            }
        }
        console.log('firebase was successfully init')
    }
}
```

How i import firebase

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import 'firebase/performance'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you import Firebase so that this code can reach it, and probably also what version of the SDK you're importing. I also *highly* recommend checking https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup, as there have been some breaking changes recently.

Comment: Please also include the Firebase SDK version in your update.

Comment: how I find  Firebase SDK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the new [Modular SDK (`V9.0.0+`)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which is designed to facilitate tree-shaking (removal of unused code) to make your web app as small and fast as possible. If you want to use your existing code (V8 name-spaced syntax) then you would have to change your imports to `compat` versions as shown below:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
// import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]'
```

However, I would recommend upgrading to the new SDK. The modular/functional syntax looks like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const app = initializeApp({ ...firebaseConfig })

const auth = getAuth(app)
const firestore = getFirestore(app)
// other Firebase services
```

You don't have to check if a default Firebase app instance already exists in the modular syntax. However, if you need to list Firebase instances, you can do so using `getApps()`:

```js
import { getApps } from 'firebase/app'

console.log(getApps())
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me, the issue started after I upgraded to Firebase 9

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'
```

My firebase initialization looks like below:

```
 let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance()
    if (!ui) {
      ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
    }
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
      signInFlow: isDesktop() ? 'popup' : 'redirect',
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult() {
          window.location.assign(`/home`)
          // firebase.auth().signOut()
          return false
        },
      },
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Firebase Auth UI library with the modular SDK yet. Check [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/837) for more details.